# Compare-Object (diff) unexpected results when importing CliXML

Tags: powershell

I am currently reading a powershell book (powershell in a month of lunches), and there is one sample in the book which is not behaving as expected.

The intention: before executing these command, i have an instance of notepad++ running. I save the response of "Get-Processes *note*". This should only return an entry for notepad++. Then i start notepad twice, and then save the output of the same command again. When i do & diff of those 2 results, i expect to see notepad, twice.

First, i'll give a sample that -does- work as intended.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $ref = gps *note*
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> notepad
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> notepad
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $cmp = gps *note*
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> diff -ref $ref -diff $cmp

InputObject                          SideIndicator
-----------                          -------------
System.Diagnostics.Process (notepad) =>
System.Diagnostics.Process (notepad) =>
```

Great! This is the expected result.
The sample below should yield the same result, but it doesnt:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd \temp
PS C:\temp> cd \temp
PS C:\temp> gps *note* | Export-Clixml ref.xml
PS C:\temp> notepad
PS C:\temp> notepad
PS C:\temp> gps *note* | Export-Clixml cmp.xml
PS C:\temp> diff -ref (Import-Clixml ref.xml) -diff (Import-Clixml cmp.xml)

InputObject                            SideIndicator
-----------                            -------------
System.Diagnostics.Process (notepad)   =>
System.Diagnostics.Process (notepad++) =>
```

This time, i get one entry mentioning notepad, and one mentioning notepad++?
How does that make sense? Can anyone clarify?

FYI: i am not executing this as a script, i am executing these command one by one.

Comment: Just to rule out lingering effects: Can you run `spps -name *note*` (kill all preexisting processes whose name matches that pattern) just before running your code and see if you still get the symptom?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer, but comments are too short to add the details:

I can repro the issue locally, but I think it's related to comparing `PSCustomObjects` rather than specifically to do with notepad / notepad++ processes and `Export-Clixml` and `Import-Clixml`. It just happens that `Import-Clixml` returns PSCustomObjects...

For example:

```bsh
PS> $x = new-object PSCustomObject -Property @{"Name" = "aaa"}
PS> $y = @( (new-object PSCustomObject -Property @{"Name" = "bbb"}), (new-object PsCustomObject -Property @{"Name" = "aaa"}) )
PS> diff $x $y

InputObject SideIndicator
----------- -------------
@{Name=aaa} =>
```